# MongoDB FlushFileBuffers failed: errno:8 Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: mongodb

I run a MongoDB Sharded Cluster version 2.6.7 64-bit, on a Windows Server 2008 R2 + SP1 64-bit. The cluster is running on the same hardware (1 machine) by running multiple instance of mongod.exe with different data folders and different ports. I have multiple database with a lot of data. 
Recently on some shards I get the following error:

```
    FlushFileBuffers failed: errno:8 Not enough storage is available to process this command. file: i:/mongodb/data/db/db.9
2015-11-10T02:12:27.662-0500 [DataFileSync] error syncing data to disk, probably a disk error
2015-11-10T02:12:27.662-0500 [DataFileSync]  shutting down immediately to avoid corruption
2015-11-10T02:12:27.662-0500 [DataFileSync] Fatal Assertion 17346
2015-11-10T02:12:39.627-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(169)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\log.cpp(127)                                  mongo::logContext+0x9c
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(139)                          mongo::fassertFailed+0x84
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap.cpp(233)                                 mongo::dataSyncFailedHandler+0x8e
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap_win.cpp(405)                             mongo::WindowsFlushable::flush+0x49c
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap.cpp(185)                                 mongo::MongoFile::_flushAll+0x23f
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap.cpp(149)                                 mongo::MongoFile::flushAll+0x20
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(537)                                     mongo::DataFileSync::run+0x260
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\background.cpp(147)                           mongo::BackgroundJob::jobBody+0x11c
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(185)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] 
2015-11-10T02:12:39.642-0500 [DataFileSync] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(169)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers.cpp(107)                      mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0xf2
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\winsig.c(593)        raise+0x1ed
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\abort.c(81)          abort+0x18
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap.cpp(233)                                 mongo::dataSyncFailedHandler+0x8e
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap_win.cpp(405)                             mongo::WindowsFlushable::flush+0x49c
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap.cpp(185)                                 mongo::MongoFile::_flushAll+0x23f
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\mmap.cpp(149)                                 mongo::MongoFile::flushAll+0x20
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(537)                                     mongo::DataFileSync::run+0x260
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\background.cpp(147)                           mongo::BackgroundJob::jobBody+0x11c
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(185)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
2015-11-10T02:12:40.422-0500 [DataFileSync] SEVERE: Got signal: 22 (SIGABRT).
```

I am sure I have enough hdd free space >400GB free on the drive where the data folder is set for that shard.

The machine has 256GB of Ram but usually Mongo is using it to a 99% ram usage. Could this be the problem?

The cluster is running in this configuration for several months with no issues until now.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
After the error occurs and the mongod shutdown, I can start the shard with no error but I don't know why the error appears and what should I do to make sure it will not appear anymore.

**EDIT 2**
This is the db.stats() output for one of the databases (database). I have about 10 databases in the cluster.

```
    {
"raw" : {
    "localhost:27018" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 60348010,
        "avgObjSize" : 1007.195495526696,
        "dataSize" : 60782243836,
        "storageSize" : 69183958576,
        "numExtents" : 59,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 20610044448,
        "fileSize" : 100816388096,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 36,
            "totalSize" : 2084864
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27019" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 72575788,
        "avgObjSize" : 1172.305104451639,
        "dataSize" : 85080966732,
        "storageSize" : 97310330208,
        "numExtents" : 73,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 25253726288,
        "fileSize" : 133012914176,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 35,
            "totalSize" : 2023424
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27020" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 60549179,
        "avgObjSize" : 1015.622328223476,
        "dataSize" : 61495098148,
        "storageSize" : 71553207840,
        "numExtents" : 61,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 20717084640,
        "fileSize" : 102962823168,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 36,
            "totalSize" : 2080768
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27021" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 29,
        "objects" : 171095871,
        "avgObjSize" : 952.4751803274083,
        "dataSize" : 162964570584,
        "storageSize" : 330010568544,
        "numExtents" : 399,
        "indexes" : 44,
        "indexSize" : 33619695648,
        "fileSize" : 478588960768,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 292,
            "totalSize" : 62521482880
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27022" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 60453876,
        "avgObjSize" : 1027.721855783077,
        "dataSize" : 62129769632,
        "storageSize" : 71553207840,
        "numExtents" : 61,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 20675959360,
        "fileSize" : 100816388096,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 35,
            "totalSize" : 2056192
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27023" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 3,
        "objects" : 84737830,
        "avgObjSize" : 2217.560954912346,
        "dataSize" : 187911303212,
        "storageSize" : 245413775632,
        "numExtents" : 141,
        "indexes" : 5,
        "indexSize" : 30231618480,
        "fileSize" : 285409804288,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 43,
            "totalSize" : 2609152
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27024" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 60892442,
        "avgObjSize" : 1471.216735633628,
        "dataSize" : 89585979744,
        "storageSize" : 90870214032,
        "numExtents" : 67,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 21297032848,
        "fileSize" : 120134303744,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 3,
            "totalSize" : 147456
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27025" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 62215729,
        "avgObjSize" : 1408.379694594594,
        "dataSize" : 87623369408,
        "storageSize" : 88723918240,
        "numExtents" : 67,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 21900282656,
        "fileSize" : 117987868672,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 3,
            "totalSize" : 147456
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27026" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 60896143,
        "avgObjSize" : 1456.349318149755,
        "dataSize" : 88686056336,
        "storageSize" : 90870345104,
        "numExtents" : 68,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 21359170448,
        "fileSize" : 120134303744,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 3,
            "totalSize" : 147456
        },
        "ok" : 1
    },
    "localhost:27027" : {
        "db" : "database",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 62024992,
        "avgObjSize" : 1420.680966278883,
        "dataSize" : 88117725568,
        "storageSize" : 90870345104,
        "numExtents" : 68,
        "indexes" : 6,
        "indexSize" : 21879736368,
        "fileSize" : 120134303744,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 3,
            "totalSize" : 147456
        },
        "ok" : 1
    }
},
"objects" : 755789860,
"avgObjSize" : 1288.761212947472,
"dataSize" : 974377083200,
"storageSize" : NumberLong(1246359871120),
"numExtents" : 1064,
"indexes" : 97,
"indexSize" : 237544351184,
"fileSize" : NumberLong(1679998058496),
"extentFreeList" : {
    "num" : 489,
    "totalSize" : 62532927104
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Why are you running multiple shards on the same server ? The error message suggest  you have run out of available disk space.

Comment: The cluster setup was not made by me and I agree it is not the best one. I do have available free space. Each shard has his own disk drive and each one has over 400GB free space.

Comment: How are you running mongod.exe ? Are you limiting the database sizes, for example by using `smallfiles`?

Comment: No, I am not using smallfiles.

Comment: Can you post the output of `db.stats` in your question?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution?